# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0. after react-native link

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-vector-icons, react-native-safe-area-view

I have a react-native project
its was OK.I run react-native link
and now when I run react-native run-android
I get  Error:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

now I run

```
./gradlew clean
```

I have this info:

> Configure project :react-native-contacts
> Subproject ':react-native-contacts' has location '/home/mohamadreza/CODES/react_native/chontact/node_modules/react-native-contacts/android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure

```
> Configure project :react-native-safe-area-context
Subproject ':react-native-safe-area-context' has location '/home/mohamadreza/CODES/react_native/chontact/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure
```

> Configure project :react-native-screens
> Subproject ':react-native-screens' has location '/home/mohamadreza/CODES/react_native/chontact/node_modules/react-native-screens/android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure
> Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're interested in inheriting the dependencies from the Configuration you are adding, you should use Configuration#extendsFrom instead. See [https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration[])](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration%5B%5D)) for more details.

> Configure project :react-native-sms
> Subproject ':react-native-sms' has location '/home/mohamadreza/CODES/react_native/chontact/node_modules/react-native-sms/android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure
> The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. JFrog announced JCenter's sunset in February 2021. Use mavenCentral() instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation
> at build_7t1wntr6nbm4h0ypkr7bjtc8c$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(/home/mohamadreza/CODES/react_native/chontact/node_modules/react-native-sms/android/build.gradle:3)
> (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

> Configure project :react-native-sqlite-storage
> Subproject ':react-native-sqlite-storage' has location '/home/mohamadreza/CODES/react_native/chontact/node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure

> Configure project :react-native-vector-icons
> Subproject ':react-native-vector-icons' has location '/home/mohamadreza/CODES/react_native/chontact/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android' which is outside of the project root. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#deprecated_flat_project_structure

anyone could help me?
react native ===> 67

classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2')

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me is changing the android Gradle version to 7.4, reference this [github issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18644#issuecomment-1191229546)